# VBA error or bug? Sheet 2 data showing in sheet 1

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have an Excel spreadsheet that started acting strangely in the last couple of days, and I'm not sure if it's my VBA code or a bug. After running a macro to add a new row of data in sheet 1 to a table in sheet 2, sheet 2 can be seen 'through'sheet 1 - it's like the cells go 'no fill' but actually show through to sheet 2 instead of being white.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Here's the spreadsheet, stored in Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8j98hGYskAwWlRrakk2cTk5LUE/view?usp=sharing), please feel free to download and look at the code etc.

Is my VBA code causing this or is it a bug, and how could I fix it?

EDIT: Here's the code. First sub is called on button press, and it calls sortTable at the end

```
Sub addRows()

    Dim rowLast As Long
    rowLast = Worksheets("Inventory").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row
    Dim relevantRow As Integer
    relevantRow = rowLast + 1

    Dim numRepeats As Integer
    Dim numRepeatsRange As Range
    Set numRepeatsRange = Range("newInv")
    numRepeats = numRepeatsRange.Count

    Dim relevantColumn As Integer
    Dim relevantColumnRange As String
    Dim copyFromCell As Range
    Dim copyToCell As Range

    Dim counter As Integer
    For counter = 1 To numRepeats
        relevantColumn = Worksheets("Index Lookup").Cells(counter + 1, 2).Value
        Set copyFromCell = Worksheets("Input").Cells(16, counter + 1)
        Set copyToCell = Worksheets("Inventory").Cells(relevantRow, relevantColumn)
        copyToCell.Value = copyFromCell.Value
    Next counter

    Call sortTable
    Worksheets("Input").Range("newInv").ClearContents
    Worksheets("Input").Range("C16").Select

End Sub


Sub sortTable()

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Inventory").ListObjects("Table14").Sort.SortFields. _
        Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Inventory").ListObjects("Table14").Sort.SortFields. _
        Add Key:=Range("C15"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Inventory").ListObjects("Table14").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

EDIT2: The cells in question reset to normal upon taking any action that directly affects them - changing worksheet, selecting them (or even dragging selection over them but not actually selecting them), editing one of the affected cells. The visual disturbance goes in front of my buttons, but if I click in that area then their macros run - this is solely a visual problem.

I've found a temporary workaround: Below the above code in sub addRows, I select cells A1:Z500, and then select C16 (selecting all clears the visual error, but it looks bad, so I reset selection to C16). The random info still flashes up on the screen but disappears really quickly.
I'd still prefer to not have to do this - any ideas?

EDIT3: I looked into it further and taking out the call to sortTable removed the problem. Something in sortTable (which only acts on sheet 2) is causing this weird visual error in sheet 1

Comment: Impossible to tell without your code - please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40878738/edit) to include it.

Comment: "my VBA code or a bug." As a general rule of thumb -- it is your code. I've made thousands of programming errors in my lifetime, but have only encountered situations where the bug is in the programming language implementations or major software tools a small number of times.

Comment: Try "editing" one of the cells on sheet1 that should be blank but appears to be showing something - does it show an existing value in the cell as you edit it?  Does the problem disappear after saving the file and then reopening it?  (My gut feeling is that it is a memory issue, perhaps not even related to Excel itself.)

Comment: Another thing that might be worth trying is inserting an `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the start of your code, and an `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was resolved when I used a different, faster computer than the one where the problem initially appeared.

Looks like YowE3k was correct and it was specific to my computer

Answer (score 1):

There can be another cause of previously selected sheet "bleeding" through to the currently visible one.

In my case, it has helped to ensure that the last visible sheet after execution of the macro was the last activated sheet in the macro using `Sheets("Name").Activate` or `Sheet.Activate`, not just selected.

Answer (score 0):

for me it worked to start the macro with

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

end ended the macro with

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```